# What happens in Simulator can happen to users as well?

Tags: ios, iphone, constraints

My app kinda screws up some constraints in the simulator if the XCode main.storyboard is set to be Viewed for an iPhone 8 but the simulator being iPhone SE for example, but if I re-run the app again with the main.storyboard set to be viewed as the phone I'm running the app, it all just works fine.

Can the users of my app get these constraints screw ups? I was getting errors that constraints were broken but I set the priority of the broken constraint to 999 and the error doesn't show up anymore.

Again, the constraints works perfectly when the Main.Storyboard view is the same with the Simulator version of the iPhone. Might it be a Xcode bug or might be a bug that shows up at random times?

Comment: No, it's not a bug. You are setting your constraints incorrectly. The whole purpose of auto-layout and constraints is to allow your interface to adjust to the different screen sizes. So, to answer your question, *absolutely* users of your app will see these "screw ups".

Comment: I tried now: I set the main.storyboard to be viewed from an iPhone 8 and I ran it on my iPhone 7 Plus  via USB. It bugged out. Stopped the running. Set the main.storyboard as iPhone 8 Plus and Run again. Constraints worked perfectly

Comment: Yes, as I said, you are setting your constraints incorrectly. Try starting a new project, add just one element to the view, assign constraints, and see if it sizes and positions itself properly.

Comment: The constraints are added correctly but it's linked to a function that rises the button with the keyboard to be sticked with the keyboard and I have to translate autoresizing mask into constraints and this is what messes it up

Comment: A tip: If you want help, describe what you are doing and post the relevant code - see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is quite impossible for anyone to help you otherwise.

Comment: Answer can be different based on what the constraint error was and how you made constraint. You better add more details.